# Using a variable that is changed within an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, variables, boolean, global-variables

I am writing a program in JAVA where I need to change a boolean, but I am not able to fix it.

The lay out is as follows

```
while(statement){
    Boolean behind = true;

    if (behind == true){
        do something
        behind = false;
        } 

    if (behind == false){
        do something else
        behind = true;
        }
}
```

So basically my program needs to iterate 'doing something' and 'doing something else'. But I reckon my boolean `behind` is not changed by the if-statement, since that 'version' of `behind` only lives within the statement. Any suggestions on how to cope with this?

Comment: declare it before the while loop

Comment: "*But I reckon my boolean behind is not changed by the if-statement, since that 'version' of behind only lives within the statement"* - that is not how scopes in Java work. For the entirety of *one* `while` loop iteration you have exactly one variable `behind` with changing values, the nested ifs all access (reading and writing) that same variable.

Comment: @giorgiga; I already tried that. But that again does not work. The boolean seems not affected by the change within the if-statement.
@luk2302: So then why does it not work?

Comment: Note that you ALWAYS execute both ifs sine your variable is defined as true, which makes the first if evaluate to true, which then sets the variable to false. Then the second if is reached and it evaluates to true as well since `behind` is `false`.

Comment: the code you show should do exactly what you want it to do. It is declared outside your if blocks, so it is not limited to the scope of the if blocks

Comment: @luk2302: that is it! Thank you. That solved the problem, much appreciated.

Comment: I received a ban because of this question because it is downvoted three times. Now I need to 'improve' this question, but I have seriously no idea how to improve it. The title seems clear, the lay out to me looks clear and it received mulitple answers. Any suggestions to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Do not use `var == true/false`.** This may reduce performance and makes the code unclear. Use `var` instead of `var == true` and `!var` instead of `var == false`.
2. **Use an `else` statement** instead of checking the condition's opposite.

```java
if (behind) {
    //...
    behind = false;
} else {
    //...
    behind = true;
}
3. **Define the boolean outside `while`.**
```

This also solves your problem because you don't "re-check" the variable.

Comment: do not use `var` as variable name - it is a special identifier in newer versions :-)   (sorry, had to write that, +1)

Comment: I received a ban because of this question because it is downvoted three times. Now I need to 'improve' this question, but I have seriously no idea how to improve it. The title seems clear, the lay out to me looks clear and it received mulitple answers. Any suggestions to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

```
Boolean behind = true;
while(statement){
    if (behind){
        do something;
        behind = false;
    }else{
        do something else;
        behind = true;
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the boolean before the while block.

```
Boolean behind = true;
while(statement){

    if (behind){
        do something;
        behind = false;
    }  else {
        do something;
        behind = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: so first `if` sets it to `false`, next `if` back to `true` - no reason to use the flag at all (missing an `else` in-between?)

Comment: I received a ban because of this question because it is downvoted three times. Now I need to 'improve' this question, but I have seriously no idea how to improve it. The title seems clear, the lay out to me looks clear and it received mulitple answers. Any suggestions to improve it?